# How should I write a height in feet and inches?

Tags: creative-writing, style, numerals

I wrote the sentence:

> From far away, he could easily be mistaken for a ten year-old, at 5’1 he was as thin as a rail and wore a flannel shirt tucked into a brown, leather belt.

I wrote 5'1. When writing height in fiction, is it 5'1? Or Five-foot-one? or neither?

Comment: That should be two sentences: "From far away, he could easily be mistaken for a ten year-old. At 5’1, he was as thin as a rail and wore a flannel shirt tucked into a brown, leather belt."

Answer (score 9):

In Chicago Manual of Style, they recommend spelling it out.

"At five foot one, he was as thin as a rail."

In some cases a hyphen may help avoid ambiguity. If it's being used as an adjective, you might add hyphens. "His five-foot-two-inch body was thin as a rail."

You can use numbers if you prefer—"He was 5'2" and small for his age"—no spaces, and be sure to add the mark for inches. There's no absolute right or wrong here. Styles vary with different publishers. The main thing is to be consistent within your story. Don't spell it out in one place and use numbers somewhere else.

Comment: Or: at five one, one ten, he was tall and buff for a ten-year-old

Comment: If you use the 5'1" form, be sure to use straight quotes, not curly quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you don’t write it in feet and inches at all. Those are antique, non-standard measurements that are understood by maybe 10% of the world population, and that number is shrinking in size every single day. You can not only make your manuscript understandable by the whole world if you use modern, standardized measurements, you can also future-proof your manuscript.

Your subject is 155 centimeters tall.

Comment: Even non-US english readers know that 5' is short and 6' tall, besides the size is further illustrated by the age comparison. 155 cm is unecessarily precise, it is a novel, not a technical manual. I think it is better just to say something like dwarfish, short, average, tall, very tall, gigantic.

Comment: I still struggle with feet and inches. Lately, one of my colleagues told me he lost a 'stone' and I had to make all sorts of clarifying questions. I know that 5' is short and 6' is tall, but I really don't know how much. I agree that describing the person is more useful.

Comment: @SimonWhite But I thought Americans expressed height in feet and inches. How is that only 10% of the world?

Comment: If this were a non-fiction work then it would be appropriate (maybe) to write "5:1 (155 cm)."  In fiction it's weird to put both and even weirder to use metric in an American novel.

Comment: @KlaraRaškaj - According to http://www.worldometers.info/world-population/us-population/ the US is barely even 5% of the world in population. Of which, I reckon a good amount of them will also understand the metric system.

Comment: @ErdrikIronrose Although they don't use them officially, there are other English-speaking countries that use feet and inches in common parlance. Also, while I'll bet most Americans understand the idea of metric system, I think most would not know immediately that, e.g., a 160 cm man is short without looking up the conversion to feet/inches.

Comment: @Reed: as a non-US English reader, I have no idea if 5' is short and 6' is tall. When I'm given heights in imperial units I simply wait for further indications later on. Sooner or later someone will mention they're tall or short, and if they don't I simply assume they're medium-height.

Comment: @Reed Why is 155 cm needlessly precise but 61 inches OK? If anything, 155 looks like it was rounded to the nearest 5. I think you just have unit chauvinism.

Comment: @J.G. unit chauvinism? i am a non-native speaker, and have no idea what 62 inches is,... feet are easy because they are about 30 cm rounded, so i know that 5 feet is about 1m50, but inches are about 2.5 cm and hard to figure out for non-americans. 155 seems too precise mostly because it is an uneven number, even ones seem more natural and for instance 1m54 or 1m56 sound ok but 1m55 is odd, the odd numbers are odd and are often rounded up, even in official documents, passports...and btw, no one using the imperial system would say 155cm, but 1m55

Comment: also, i feel 1m55 is too precise for a character in a novel, i dont see much of a difference between 1m50, 1m55, 1m60 unless it is an important point, like being almost 1m60 and feeling inadequate and lying about it and wearing platform shoes and a big hairdo, though i guess being precise could ad a note of realism, but odd numbers still seem jarring imo

Comment: @Simon White while i am commenting again if the book is being targeted for the US, market,  the use of the imperial system is essential. most books will never reach outside of their small pond, and unless it is a technical or scientific manual,  if it uses cm, it may as well be written in Swahili.....Americans are notorious for being basically incapable of learning other languages, measurement systems, foreign customs,  traditions, ideas, cultures....it is all Alien to them

Comment: @Reed OK, 5'1" then. But why is that less needlessly precise than a number of centimetres, be it a multiple of 5 or 2 or any other factor you've noticed before? Perhaps the answer's author will be grateful to you for suggesting 1m55 over 155cm (even if someone using the imperial system would by definition say neither), but an extra 5 cm or 2" isn't too precise. People routinely insist on getting heights right to the inch, or even half- or quarter-inch, because most "tall" people are within a few inches of most "short" ones.

Comment: @J.G: it seems that way because inches are a larger unit and hence less precise. and 5´1" could mean anything between 5´and 5´2".. i have never heard someone say half and quarter inch when speaking about human heights. maybe it is cultural, but where i come from people routinely round up, usually to the larger even number, if someone is 1m77,  he will says he is 1m78 then he is almost 1m80 and would likely say to Americans he is 6 feet, or "almost" 6 feet (though thechnically that is 182 cm 88 mm)

Comment: @Reed I won't comment on the even-cm thing. The inch/half-inch/quarter-inch precision depends on how petty one's characters are being, but it's entirely true to life occasionally.

Comment: It depends who your intended audience is. If you are writing for Americans, use imperial units.  One exception might be sci-fi, where characters might be expected to use metric.